# Text inside inputfield is too close to the border

Tags: css, input-field

I have an input field that has a gradient border, but the text inside is too close to it. 
And I have already tried `padding-left`, but that made the border on the left bigger, and the text was still close to the border.

The picture of the input field:

[image]

```css
.inputfield {
    margin-top: 5px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    outline:0;
    width: 170px;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: white;

    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;

    background-color: rgb(11, 15, 31);
    border: solid 0.5px transparent;
    border-radius: 80px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(11, 15, 31), rgb(11, 15, 31)), radial-gradient(circle at top 
    left, rgb(76, 133, 242),rgb(144, 104, 235));
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
```

[This is what it does when add padding-left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H7ud.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce a wrapper element around your `input`. A quick example built into your existing code would look something like this:

```css
.input-wrapper {
    width: 170px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 80px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(11, 15, 31), rgb(11, 15, 31)), radial-gradient(circle at top 
    left, rgb(76, 133, 242),rgb(144, 104, 235));
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.input-field {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input class="input-field" value="TEXT">  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add padding-left to input[type=text].

Comment: I tried adding that, but it makes the border on the left bigger and the text is still close to the border.